# How to fix items inside popup not centering?

Tags: javascript, css, toast, sweetalert2

As you can see, the items in the popup are cut off due to the smaller height.

[image]

How do I make the title and loading icon center within the popup?

Here is my code:

```js
Swal.fire({
  toast: true,
  icon: 'info',
  title: 'Restoring messages...',
  animation: true,
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: false,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  allowEnterKey: false,
  position: 'top',
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.showLoading();
  }
});
```

```css
.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-show,
.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-hide {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding `padding: 0` to your css code. What happens behind the scenes is that you are giving a limited height so it seems like not centered, but it is actually.

The CSS code:

```
.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-show, .swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-hide {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image: Before:]

[image: After:]

Comment: what element do I add it to?

Comment: Updated my answer with CSS code, please check it out @Vlone. Basically you just need to add `padding: 0;` to the classes(`.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-show, .swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-hide`) you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks, @AgilAtakishiyev! And, another question, how would I make the text size stay the same (not get smaller)?

Comment: When does the text get smaller? you mean generally how to change its `font-size`? Or there are specific cases where it gets smaller without intention? @Vlone